# Not able to return error to calling function inside Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Hi i am trying to get the error return code to my calling function inside ionic, but I am not able to return the error from the function called.

Here is my main page where the function is called:

```
let result:any = await this.authService.SignUp(
        this.registerForm.value["name"], 
        this.registerForm.value["phone"],
        this.registerForm.value["email"], 
        this.registerForm.value["password"],
        this.attorneyId
      );
      if (result && result.code) {
        console.log('Register Page Error', result.code); //NOT GETTING RESULT HERE 
        this.alertService.showErrorMessage(result.code);

      }
```

here is my function which is called from above:

```
async SignUp(
    fullName: string,
    phone: number,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    attid: number
  ) {
    console.log("Inside Auth SignUp");
    this.afDatabase.list("/attorneyList", ref =>
        ref.orderByChild("attid").equalTo(attid)
      ).valueChanges().subscribe(async data => {
        console.log("Inside Data")
        if (data[0]) {
          return await this.afAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(async result => {
              console.log("Signup Result", result)
              result.user["fullName"] = fullName;
              result.user["phone"] = phone;
              result.user["attid"] = attid;
              await this.SetUserData(result.user);
              this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(["/tabs"]);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("Signup Error", error); //GETTING ERROR HERE
              return error; //THIS IS NOT RETURNING THE ERROR BACK TO THE ABOVE CALLING FUNCTION
            });
        }
      });

  }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here??? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` inside your `subscribe` call on the firestore query does not actually return that data from the function. you could, however, convert your query into a promise by calling `.valueChanges().pipe(first()).toPromise()` and `await` the result of that query. then the code, that is currently inside your `subscribe` call should work as expected.

```js
async SignUp(
    fullName: string,
    phone: number,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    attid: number
  ) {
    console.log("Inside Auth SignUp");
    const data = await this.afDatabase.list("/attorneyList", ref =>
        ref.orderByChild("attid").equalTo(attid)
      ).valueChanges().pipe(first()).toPromise();
        console.log("Inside Data")
        if (data[0]) {
          return await this.afAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(async result => {
              console.log("Signup Result", result)
              result.user["fullName"] = fullName;
              result.user["phone"] = phone;
              result.user["attid"] = attid;
              await this.SetUserData(result.user);
              this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(["/tabs"]);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("Signup Error", error); //GETTING ERROR HERE
              return error; //THIS IS NOT RETURNING THE ERROR BACK TO THE ABOVE CALLING FUNCTION
            });
        }
  }
```

That code should demonstrate my solution